# Array size limits

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have an array problem that i want to overcome, if i change the value of const int "are" to 2048 the program runs fine but at 8192 or even at 4096 ( just 130,000 elements) it does not work and breaks. How do i get around this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma warning (disable : 4820 4619 4668 4101)

HANDLE ghEvents;

const int arc = 2048; 
const int are = 8192;

struct DataStructure_init {

    int main_seq[are][32];
    int main_seq2[are][32];
    int main_seq3[are][32];
    int main_lim[are];

};

struct DataStructure_trus {
    int net[arc]; 
    int  r6[arc];
    int thr[arc];
};

int ftrus (unsigned char cmain[],int array_inst[],DataStructure_trus& va);
int finit (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char cmain[are];
    int array_inst[64]={0};
    DataStructure_trus va; 
    DataStructure_init in;
    ftrus(cmain,array_inst,va);
    finit(va,in);

    cin.get();
}



int finit (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in)
{

    int nb=0,flag=0,lock=0;

    for(int i=0;i<are;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<24;j++){
        in.main_seq[i][j]=va.thr[(i*24)+j];
        }

    }

    return 0;
}



int ftrus (unsigned char cmain[],int array_inst[],DataStructure_trus& va)
{

    int g=0; 
    ifstream in("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\DCS\\Decom\\trus.txt", ios::binary);
    unsigned char c;
    while( in.read((char *)&c, 1) )
    {       
            cmain[g]=c;
            if(cmain[g]==' ' && cmain[g-1]=='t' && cmain[g-2]=='e' && cmain[g-3]=='n')      {array_inst[1]=g+1;}
            else if(cmain[g]==' ' && cmain[g-1]=='r' && cmain[g-2]=='h' && cmain[g-3]=='t') {array_inst[9]=g+1;array_inst[21]=g-7;}
            g++;
    }
    array_inst[29]=g-2;

    for(int i=0;i<64;i++){va.r6[i]=0;}

    for(int i=array_inst[1];i<array_inst[21];i++){
        if(cmain[i]=='1'){va.net[va.r6[1]]=1;va.r6[1]++;}
                    else {va.net[va.r6[1]]=0;va.r6[1]++;}
    }

    for(int i=array_inst[9];i<array_inst[29];i++){
        if(cmain[i]=='1'){va.thr[va.r6[9]]=1;va.r6[9]++;}
                    else {va.thr[va.r6[9]]=0;va.r6[9]++;}
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you write "_just_ 130,000 elements". On what basis do you assume that this is not a lot?

Comment: So can i do something like this create a pointer in the data structure and allocate the space dynamically in the main ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: @ Lightness Races : Well i've had no problems creating single sized arrays with 250,000 elements, so i assumed 130,000 was not much and thought the system should have handled that.i didn't realize there was a stack limit.

Comment: 250,000 _whats_? 130,000 `int`s is likely to be at least 520K. Depending on the place in your program where you use it, and how much memory is taken by _other_ things on the stack, that could push you over the top of your stack.

Comment: how do i find out the limit of my stack ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I know that you can, but I've never done it myself because it would be the wrong way to program. Someone else may recall how to determine it for curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to put the arrays on the stack in main(), you can just as well allocate them statically before entering the function. That will put them in an area that is not limited by the default stack size.

```
unsigned char cmain[are];
int array_inst[64]={0};
DataStructure_trus va;
DataStructure_init in;

int main() {
   ftrus(cmain,array_inst,va);
   finit(va,in);
   cin.get();
 }
```

Comment: this works wonders, declaring the data structure outside the main, even with "are" as 20,000 the program executes without a glitch.

Answer (score 5):

Allocate the array dynamically, since there are often limits on how much data you can have on the stack (which is where automatic local variables typically end up):

```
unsigned char* cmain = new unsigned char[are];
```

Comment: I was scared of doing that because my program is much bigger and crashes a lot, what happens if i haven't deleted the memory and my program crashes before that, would the processor de-allocate the memory ?

Comment: @Gambit: Make your program not crash.

Comment: @GambitKing: All memory allocated by a process is freed when it terminates. So, a program crash automatically frees your memory.

Comment: @GambitKing, if your program crashes, everything will be taken from it.

Comment: Is there any free program that i can use that that frees the memory after these kind of crashes ?

Comment: @thiton: That's implementation-specific!

Comment: @GambitKing: As you were just informed, there is usually no need for such a thing. The allocated memory is recovered when the process ends -- usually. C++ doesn't actually define that, but modern OSs do.

Comment: oh ok, so using delete[] variable is not that compulsary,it just affects the performance of the system while the program is running after which the memory is freed. thanks

Comment: It's not "compulsory" at all... it's just a very good idea. Even if you know that you're only allocating once in your program, get into the habit of cleaning up the memory, so that you don't end up with growing leaks during execution. You _should_ use a standard container instead of `new`ing yourself.

Comment: @GambitKing You're actually not allocating physical memory at all on any modern, general-purpose OS, you're allocating address space, virtual memory. When a process terminates, its address space ceases to exist. So it is logically impossible for it not to be freed.

Answer (score 3):

What everyone else said: you're trying to allocate a lot of stuff on the stack. A *lot*.

Instead, dynamically-allocate the memory buffer... by using a standard container for memory management:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> cmain(are);
```

Comment: Whenever i use vectors my programs runs twice as slow, i know its my implementation that is the problem though.

Comment: Then you're using vectors incorrectly. When you properly `reserve` capacity as possible, vector usage has the same speed as that of arrays. Standard containers are the correct approach here. They take care of allocation and of clean-up for you. And they're free.

Comment: Also, if you enable optimizations it should run as fast as with a regular C-style array, since, once the `operator[]` calls are inlined, the generated code should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the data structure on the stack in `main`, and it is pretty huge. You can either increase the stack size (depends on your system), or allocate the structure on the heap with `new` or `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with allocating `DataStructure_*` not in the stack. For instance by prepending the `static` keyword.

```
static DataStructure_trus va; 
static DataStructure_init in;
```

Comment: ... which will result in an enormous executable. The right solution here is to use the heap.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, that's why "start with". This is an attempt to minimize changes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you may be misguided now into being proud of your witty comment.

Comment: Was there any to be offensive? :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: why an enormous executable?  That's an uninitialized declaration, isn't it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: yep, looking at the code now it does seem so; I don't know what I was thinking three years ago. :-/