# Having large 2d arrays : static int vs int

Tags: c++, arrays

While solving a DP related problem, I observed that first works but the second seg faults .
What is the actual reason and what is the memory limit for just using int ?

```
int main(){
    static int a[3160][3160];
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int a[3160][3160];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array size limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016538/array-size-limits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you probably don't have enough stack memory to store that big array.

Second Example creates an array on stack, while the First example creates an array which is not located on stack but somewhere in the data/Bss segment, since you explicitly specify the storage criteria using `static` qualifier.

Note that c++ standard does not specify `stack` or `heap` or `data segment` or `Bss segment` these are all implementation defined details. The standard only specify's behavior expected of variables declared with different storage criteria. So, *where* the variables are actually *created* is implementation defined but one thing for sure is, both your examples will create the arrays in different memory regions and the second one crashes because there is not enough memory in that region.

Also, probably if you are creating an array of such huge dimensions in actual implementation your design seems flawed and you might want to consider revisiting it.

You might also want to consider using **[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)** or **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**, instead of the traditional c-style arrays.

Comment: "examples will create the arrays in different memory regions" What I thought was happening - Short and Nice ,If no other answer , I ll mark this one :)

Answer (score 1):

A stack allocation that large is not safe (unless you were to fulfill that guarantee).

The stack size varies by platform/hardware. Therefore, the 'memory limit' varies dramatically. If you use huge stack arrays like this, be prepared to see this error often when your program is run on an processor other than the one you use for development. If you *absolutely need* a stack that large, you must create your own threads with explicit stack sizes.

However, that measure is not needed because you should just use a dynamic allocation here.

`static` is not a good choice if you need it to be reentrant.

As Als noted (+1) - the reason for the runtime error is very likely the stack size.