# Is there way to increase memory of an array? and Related issue

Tags: c++, windows

Simple problem:
My code blocks of able to compile the code below and worked well:

```
int a[2000000];
```

My code blocks of able to compile the code below **But my program crashed immediately after**:

```
int a[2000000];
int b[2000000];
```

1) What is the reason and why? (my ram 16 GB !! and this just took 0.3MB so whats the problem?)

2) How to fix or use an alternate way? (but i need to create so much of arrays)

3) Is there way to increase memory of an array?

---

Related problem(i think so):

My code blocks of able to compile the code below and worked well:

```
unsigned long int a=100000000000;
```

My code blocks of able to compile the code below **But my program crashed immediately after i enter the same number(100000000000)**:

```
unsigned long int a;
 cin>>a;
```

What to do?

Comment: Probably stack overflow. In general, forget arrays and use `std::vector` or other standard containers.

Comment: i don't think that any c++ beginner would need to declare an array of size `2000000`

Comment: Do you really need that much of an automatic storage? If you do, you'd have to increase your stack limit.

Comment: My issue with the dupe closure is that it is a C question.  The remedy in the accepted answer gives advice that is not best practice/recommended in C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I do agree with you. Should we reopen and have a canonical C++ answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Good point. I failed to notice that. Would this one be better? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9016538/10077

Comment: @SergeyA I almost think the other question getting tagged as C++ and adding a C++ work around to the accepted answer would be the best thing.  Not sure if Borgleader is up for that,

Comment: @FredLarson I went ahead and closed it as a dupe your suggestion.  Still think we might want to improve the C one to be C,C++ but that might need a meta question to get community approval.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I know what you mean. That ASCII art explanation is very good and language agnostic.

Comment: sorry! guys! i have added a few!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int a[2000000];
> ```

That overflows your stack limit. You can use a `std::vector<int> a(2000000);` instead, which will use dynamic storage allocation (which is unlimited theoretically).

Comment: but the problem is i dont know much about vector! but anyway is there any that i can fix this using arrays only!

Comment: @Aravind.KEN There's not much to know about it:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector . No, there's no way using raw arrays to do that.

Comment: @Aravind.KEN It's a good time to start reading about them!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its my class project -- Sieve of Eratosthenes ! i wanna find prime numbers more than 2000000!! and vector is not there in my portions!!

Comment: ***is there any that i can fix this using arrays only!*** Increase the stack size of your program.

Comment: @drescherjm How to?

Comment: @Aravind.KEN, you can use dynamic arrays if you must.

Comment: @Aravind.KEN _"How to?"_ Depends on your operating system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Windows 10 64 bit! 16GB ram! i7 processor

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ! My idea ! can i use two separate program and create array       and share the memory !?

Comment: @MarcoA gave you the MSVC documentation how to do that.

Comment: @Aravind.KEN No, I meant there are commands you can use to increase a programs stack size, like `ulimit` in linux (don't know the windows equivalent, sorry)

Comment: ***My idea ! can i use two separate program and create array and share the memory !?*** Much easier to use a vector or even an old dynamic array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ pls check my question again! i have added a bit!

Comment: @Aravind.KEN I don't think your additions are anyhow related to the original problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its memory problem right?

Comment: @Aravind.KEN It's your stack limit dude!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  ok thx bro! pls edit my question! sorry bro ! i am unable to choose any of ur and other answers as i dont know anyway thing about it to choose the right one!! thx guys!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ anyway bro! what would ur answer for the second problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Compiled executables have stack limits

([MSVC docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx))

> Without this option the stack size defaults to 1 MB.

Your code is overflowing the stack space

```
int a[2000000];
```

Stack is a precious limited resource, if you need to allocate huge chunks of memory consider doing it in the heap.

Cfr. [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: but heap memory handing is dangerous right !?

Comment: @Aravind.KEN That is why you should use a `std::vector`.  It is safe and will solve your problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well understood sir! any nice website to know about it ! and i have added extra in question! pls try answer as well!